# How to run msysgit from Cygwin?

Tags: windows, git, github, cygwin, msysgit

How can I run msysgit (the Windows version of git distributed by github) work in the Cygwin environment?

Cygwin's own git breaks when you try to use it on Windows network shares - msysgit doesn't have that problem, but I can't figure out how to get it working in Cygwin.

(Cygwin's Unix-y environment is far better than the minimal one supplied with msysgit, so I want to make this work under Cygwin.)

A few things I've tried that don't work:

- Copying git.exe into Cygwin's bin directory (complains about missing dlls)
- Also copying the dlls (complains about not finding the .../share folder that tells it how to https)
- Various tricks with junctions

I'm stumped at this point. Is this even possible?

Or - is there a way to make Cygwin's git work on a network share?

=====================================================

**ADDED 4 DEC 2014:** On more investigation, I've discovered msysgit works OK under Cygwin when cloning *public* repositories, but not when cloning *private* ones (from GitHub).

I added msysgit's .../bin directory to the end of $PATH in Cygwin (Cygwin's own git is not currently installed).  Cloning a public repository works fine, but when I try to clone a private one I get:

msysgit on Cygwin:

```
dave@ENOUGH /cygdrive/z
$ git clone https://github.com/nerdfever/MouseCam
Cloning into 'MouseCam'...
```

[it just sits there until I hit ^C]

But it works fine in cmd.exe:

```
Z:\>git clone https://github.com/nerdfever/MouseCam
Cloning into 'MouseCam'...
remote: Counting objects: 35, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 35 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (35/35), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

Z:\>
```

My GitHub credentials are stored in c:\Users\Dave\.git-credentials, which contains:

```
https://nerdfever:<...long hex string...>@github.com
```

I think my core problem is that msysgit isn't reading these credentials properly under Cygwin, even tho it works fine both under cmd.exe and under msysgit's own bash shell.

But why, and how to fix?

**ADDED 330pm:**

I almost have this working. After I copied .gitconfig and .git-credentials from the msysgit location (c:\Users\Dave) into Cygwin's ~ , git completes the clone.

The sole remaining problem is that msysgit is missing it's normal verbosity (and -v doesn't help). Under Cygwin:

```
dave@ENOUGH /cygdrive/z
$ git clone https://github.com/nerdfever/MouseCam -v
Cloning into 'MouseCam'...
POST git-upload-pack (262 bytes)

dave@ENOUGH /cygdrive/z
```

Compare to what I get under cmd.exe (see above).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a bad idea, but if you insist you could do it like
this

```sh
set /cygdrive/c/msysgit/bin/git /usr/local/bin
cp $1 $2
ldd $1 |
awk '$0~"/bin" && !seen[$0]++ {print $3}' |
xargs cp -t $2
```

This will

- copy `git` to `/usr/local/bin`
- copy `git` requirements to `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/local/bin` is by Cygwin default top of the PATH, so should run even
  before Cygwin Git

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/4e0992f8c1d6ed757/baby-cygwin.sh#L58)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it almost works (permission issues...), but the mysysgit requirements folder inlcude a lot of standard Unix commands that I'd prefer to not have replace the Cygwin ones.... Care to explain why it's a bad idea and what I ought to be doing instead?  I'd use the Cygwin git, but as stated it doesn't work on network shares.

Comment: @nerdfever.com what is the latest version of Cygwin Git you have tried?

Comment: "git version 1.9.4.mysysgit.1". That's the one I get from GitHub. The Cygwin version I tried (problems writing to network shares) was 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

> I almost have this working. After I copied .gitconfig and .git-credentials from the msysgit location (c:\Users\Dave) into Cygwin's ~ , git completes the clone.

This worked for me. I copied .gitconfig and the contents of .ssh from msysgit's home to Cygwin's home.